# Programmed radio playback fails

Tags: sonos

I am trying to build a content service for Sonos and I am having trouble playing tracks. I have managed to set up a very basic SMAPI server and added the Cloud Queue endpoints, and eventually figured out how to make the manifest work. No authentication is involved, and HTTPS is only used for the manifest file since it doesn’t work otherwise.

Now after I load the custom SD onto the Sonos speaker, it calls `getMetadata`, `getLastUpdate`, `context` and `itemWindow` and I return the appropriate responses (see JSON below), identical to the ones shown in the Sonos docs. My root `mediaCollection` is a list of programs, referred to as a programmed radios in the documentation. The tracks I return in the queue contain a `mediaUrl` which points to my computer so I can track whenever it is used.

However, the URLs are never used and content is never played on my speaker. If I press play I get the error “Unable to play the selected item” but nothing helpful to figure out what is wrong. I have checked that my media files are supported and appropriate for streaming, and they are but the player never even attempts to access them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**`itemWindow` response:**

```json
{
    "queueVersion": "34612290",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "21580176",
            "deleted": false,
            "track": {
                "name": "Back Together (Dub)",
                "album": {
                    "name": "Back Together - Single",
                    "artist": {
                        "name": "Jean & Trevor"
                    }
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Jean & Trevor"
                },
                "imageUrl": "http://192.168.1.38:3040/covers/E9JRtSpc5F2wAARjS.png",
                "mediaUrl": "http://192.168.1.38:3040/tracks/E9JRtSpc5F2wAARjS.m4a",
                "durationMillis": 421700,
                "contentType": "audio/mp4",
                "id": {
                    "objectId": "track_E9JRtSpc5F2wAARjS"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "00291014",
            "deleted": false,
            "track": {
                "name": "Bajoo",
                "album": {
                    "name": "Tropical Bird Club",
                    "artist": {
                        "name": "JaJa"
                    }
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "JaJa"
                },
                "imageUrl": "http://192.168.1.38:3040/covers/kY3kTCKg75GTbTfTQ.png",
                "mediaUrl": "http://192.168.1.38:3040/tracks/kY3kTCKg75GTbTfTQ.m4a",
                "durationMillis": 378000,
                "contentType": "audio/mp4",
                "id": {
                    "objectId": "track_kY3kTCKg75GTbTfTQ"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "00582217",
            "deleted": false,
            "track": {
                "name": "La maison où j'ai grandi (Il Ragazzo Della Via Gluck)",
                "album": {
                    "name": "La maison où j'ai grandi",
                    "artist": {
                        "name": "Françoise Hardy"
                    }
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Françoise Hardy"
                },
                "imageUrl": "http://192.168.1.38:3040/covers/xucsWSjnPGgwXGbpy.png",
                "mediaUrl": "http://192.168.1.38:3040/tracks/xucsWSjnPGgwXGbpy.m4a",
                "durationMillis": 216000,
                "contentType": "audio/mp4",
                "id": {
                    "objectId": "track_xucsWSjnPGgwXGbpy"
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    ],
    "includesBeginningOfQueue": true,
    "includesEndOfQueue": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your getMetadata return? I'm confused by your json, SMAPI doesn't use json (except in a few undocumented cases). That and getLastUpdate should be sufficient to get a playback call. Do you see your root objects in the Sonos app?

I write Sonos apps that use SMAPI and I don't use json ever except for the undocumented stuff necessary for a few of the services. (I don't do any cloud queue stuff).

I suggest getting the basics of SMAPI working before trying the cloud queue integration (cloud queue is optional and can be done later).